# Cos'è (o era) un "facchino di piazza"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Non avrebbero saputo che fare se, accanto alla finestra, rovesciato su una coltre, a testa all'ingiù, il torso nudo, non avessero scorto Anastasio, il gigante greco, un *facchino di piazza* che due anni prima aveva divertito Firenze per la sua statura; e ora campava la vita senza che nessuno ne facesse più meraviglia.

Questa espressione, *facchino di piazza*, appare più avanti nel libro alcune altre volte, per esempio:

> Eccolo che si avanza confidenziale e quasi ammicca: non è più il garzone di tanti anni fa, è invecchiato male, macro e nero, già canuto, col costume sbrindellato del *facchino di piazza*, mestiere che la padrona gli permette di esercitare a tempo perduto, per economia.

Un altro brano afferma che questo personaggio era "un facchino del mercato".

Ho cercato il vocabolo "facchino" in alcuni dizionari; tuttavia, non riesco a capire cos'è o cos'era un "facchino di piazza". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: **hint**: 

- se la frase appare nel libro un'altra volta sola (singolare) allora scriverai _"appare più avanti nel libro un'altra volta"_ (oppure: _"ancora una volta"_) 

- se appare invece diverse volte ancora, puoi usare "alcune altre" al **plurale**, o più semplicemente "altre volte": _"appare più avanti nel libro altre volte"_ o _"appare più avanti nel libro alcune altre volte"_ 

**p.s.**: sei comunque una bravissima autodidatta ^_^

Comment: Grazie mille, @maxadamo! Ho fatto la correzione.

Answer (score 1):

Si tratta di lavoratori che usano il luogo pubblico della piazza come se fosse il loro ufficio. 
Vuol dire semplicemente che la gente che ha bisogno del facchino, sa che può trovarlo nel suo ufficio, ovvero nella piazza. 
In tempi più recenti (circa 20 anni fa) mi ricordo i traslocatori di piazza, che stavano con la moto Ape ape parcheggiata in una piazzetta.

Comment: Quindi, questi "facchini di piazza" del Seicento sarebbero persone che venivano richieste per strada per trasportare pacchi?

Answer (score 0):

Nel libro "[Uomini con le spalle larghe](http://www.cftlogistica.it/pagineLibro/Libro-CFT-Uomini-con-le-spalle-larghe.pdf)", nel primo capitolo, viene spiegata l'origine del termine e come abbia assunto il significato contemporaneo.
Nel mondo arabo i *faqih* erano dei giuristi che si occupavano di dirimere questioni relative alla dogana. Successivamente tra i secoli XI-XVI, erano definiti con questa parola, semplicemente dei funzionati di dogana.
Nei secoli XIV-XV, con il decadimento economico del mondo arabo-islamico, i facchini iniziarono anche a svolgere mansioni più manuali, da questa pratica nasce l'utilizzo sarcastico, da parte dei veneziani, della parola facchino come uomo di fatica.

Nella Roma rinascimentale i facchini erano coloro che prestavano servizio al Papa, trasportando acqua per la città, fino a quando gli acquedotti romani furono rispristinati:

> molto probabilmente sono tutte fantasie popolari perchè questo busto
>   rappresenta un "acquarolo", impropriamente soprannominato "facchino",
>   uno di coloro cioè che di notte riempivano botti e botticelle con
>   l'acqua del Tevere o dell'abbondante acqua della Fontana di Trevi e di
>   giorno la vendevano per strada o direttamente per le case. Questo
>   mestiere durò circa fino alla fine del Cinquecento, quando cioè i
>   pontefici ripristinarono gli antichi Acquedotti romani

Nell'età moderna fino ad alcuni decenni fa, erano lavoratori "a giornata", di bassa estrazione sociale, che si trovavano nelle piazze e aspettavano che qualcuno gli desse un incarico.

> [..] della coop “Redenta” che fin dai primi del ‘900 riuniva i facchini del
>   vecchio mercato di piazza Ghiberti. Tutti ex detenuti del carcere
>   delle Murate, che caricando e scaricando camion di frutta ogni giorno
>   cercavano un’occasione di riscatto sociale. [Fonte](http://www.agenziaimpress.it/quarantanni-di-storia-per-la-cooperativa-di-facchini-da-300mln-di-fatturato/)

Se il testo è ambientato nel seicento forse la parola ha ancora il suo significato originario. Nel libro [Leggi del Gran-Ducato della Toscana](https://books.google.it/books?id=27QYCdSWWfwC&pg=RA1-PA92&lpg=RA1-PA92&dq=facchino%20di%20piazza&source=bl&ots=77Hq7NBVXf&sig=XtzpGM8swJFalHryHK75j8_PjsM&hl=it&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjb8Iakk-PKAhXF1ywKHWpODugQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=facchino%20di%20piazza&f=false) vengono ancora descritti come incaricati a attività di dogana e supervisione.

Comment: Tenendo conto che questo accade nella prima metà del Seicento, il "facchino di piazza" o "del mercato" potrebbe essere un venditore ambulante di acqua o di altre merci?

Comment: @Charo: credo che l'acqua credo la portassero solo i facchini di Roma (da quello che ho capito). Ho aggiornato la risposta con altre fonti.

Comment: In questo libro, però, sembra che si parli dei "facchini di Piazza" e i "facchini di Dogana" come due cose diverse.

Comment: Sì, da quello che ho capito io, i facchini di piazza sono aiutanti dei facchini di dogana.